# Error using ltm R package

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I'm using the R package [ltm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/index.html) to create a 2-parameter logistic regression.

The input matrix is sparse - many users have taken a small subset of the items in the item bank.

For some of my data sets i'm running into this error:

```
Error in if (any(ind <- pr == 0)) pr[ind] <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Not sure what the issue is.  Doesn't repro on most of my data sets.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the R code which raised this error? Are you using the `ltm` function?

Comment: My code is very simple:

 pmodel <- ltm(pivot2 ~ z1)

where pivot2 is my item ~ user dataframe.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue (after much pain):

If any of the item columns contains less than two question responses, then the library will throw the above error.  The solution was to drop any columns (items) that didn't meet that criteria.

Answer (score 4):

I think I figured out the issue (after much pain):

If any of the item columns contains less than two question responses (i.e. the rest are NA), then the library will throw the above error. The solution was to drop any columns (items) that didn't meet that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem, but my data has no NA. Instead, the problem seems to be because many columns are duplicate. The problem goes away if I only keep distinct columns, but I [don't know](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515549/irt-analysis-duplicate-columns) how this impacts the IRT analysis.