# IRT analysis: duplicate columns?

Tags: r, item-response-theory

I am trying to create a 2-parameter logistic regression model. My data has no `NA`'s, 233 rows (plus 1 header row),  and 458 columns of 0's and 1's only (but many columns are duplicate). I am able to create a Rasch model:

```
> library(ltm)
> ds <- read.csv("data.csv")
> m0 <- rasch(ds)
> summary(m0)

Call:
rasch(data = ds)

Model Summary:
   log.Lik      AIC      BIC
 -13074.27 27066.55 28650.58
...
```

But I get an error with this:

```
> m1 <- ltm(ds ~ z1)
Error in if (any(ind <- pr == 1)) pr[ind] <- 1 - sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

(Exactly the same problem was reported earlier on [StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46661/error-using-ltm-r-package#new-answer?newreg=5252fcf373924ed78c5483a02663b624) and on [GitHub](https://github.com/drizopoulos/ltm/issues/1), but the suggested fix applies only when columns have many `NA`'s.)

If I keep only distinct columns and remove duplicate columns (i.e., items with identical responses for all 233 subjects), it seems to work:

```
> m1 <- ltm(ds ~ z1)
> summary(m1)

Call:
ltm(formula = ds ~ z1)

Model Summary:
   log.Lik      AIC     BIC
 -2273.663 4671.326 4885.29
...
```

So my question is: Is it OK to drop duplicate columns in an IRT analysis (i.e., keep one copy only)?

Note: I also tried running the 3-parameter model and I get the same warning with and without duplicates:

```
 m2 <- tpm(ds)
Warning message:
In tpm(ds) :
  Hessian matrix at convergence contains infinite or missing values; unstable solution.
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I was able to find [this 2015 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Seonghee-Sophia-Cho/publication/276148276_An_Investigation_of_Emotional_Intelligence_Measures_Using_Item_Response_Theory/links/55a8190e08ae481aa7f56bde/An-Investigation-of-Emotional-Intelligence-Measures-Using-Item-Response-Theory.pdf) in which the authors "deleted respondents who had duplicate responses" (column 2 on page 5 of the PDF... page 4 of the paper) prior to their IRT analysis. There is no discussion on whether this is always OK to do.

Comment: I emailed one of the authors of the above paper -- it seems that they deleted all but one response from respondents who submitted more than once (the responses themselves could have been different). So this paper does not address the question I have raised.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is more of a data collection/management question as opposed to statistical. For instance, do you know enough about the data file to convince yourself that this was not some error? From experience, I can say this happens more than is typically expected. Given this, I would suggest removing the duplicate columns.

Comment: Thanks R_user123! Yes, I know this isn't an error with the data. I'm using IRT in a Computer Science educational context -- I'm running buggy programs against a suite of tests created by students. Each test suite ("subject" in the IRT sense) deterministically produces a pass/fail pattern when run against all buggy programs ("items" in the IRT sense). I'm getting duplicate columns because multiple buggy programs produce are "similarly wrong" from the viewpoint of these tests. My goal is to score test suite quality ("theta" from the IRT analysis), so does it make sense to drop columns here?